# Java - Implementing a Queue into a Stack?

Tags: java, linked-list, stack, queue

I've created the below code and I'm mean't to implement a Stack and a Queue. Now I've implemented the Stack having thought I implemented a Queue so I'm wondering where and how I can implement a Queue. Baring in mind I have to feed the stacks using a Queue but I seem to have bypassed that :)

Any help is hugely appreciated!

```
package stackandqueue;


import java.util.*;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StackAndQueue 
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
// Create three empty stacks of Bays.
// Bay 1 linked list
Queue<String> bayoneStack = new LinkedList<String>();
// Bay 2 linkd list.
Queue<String> baytwoStack = new LinkedList<String>();
// Bay 3 linked list
Queue<String> baythreeStack = new LinkedList<String>();


Queue<String> bayloadStack = new LinkedList<String>();



System.out.println("***********************************************");

// Open and read text file
String inputFileName = "PodData4.txt";
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("PodData4.txt");

// Create the FileReader object
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);)
{    
// Sort the data into the relevant linked list by type F, T or P.
String[] strings = br.readLine().split(",");
for (String str : strings)
{
    switch (str.charAt(0))
    {
        case 'F':
            bayoneStack.add(str);
            break;
        case 'T':
            baytwoStack.add(str);
            break;
        case 'P':
            baythreeStack.add(str);
            break;
        default:
            // In-case of invalid input

    }

    System.out.println(str);



}
} 
catch(IOException ex)
{
//handle exception;
}
finally
{
fileReader.close();
}
// Prints out the linked list stacks showing all Bays.
System.out.println("***********************************************");

System.out.println("Bay 1:Food: " + bayoneStack.toString());
System.out.println("Bay 2:Technical: " + baytwoStack.toString());
System.out.println("Bay 3:Personal: " + baythreeStack.toString());

}
}
```

Comment: Can you fix your indentation please?

Comment: Please ask a clear, specific question. What do you want to do? What output do you expect for a certain input? What are 'F', 'T' and 'P'?

Comment: Ok, so I'm getting the output(SHOWN BELOW) I want but I need to implement a queue into the code. But I don't know where to implement it.                                                                                                                                                                                                                            Bay 1:Food: [F99, F14, F58, F77, F63, F53]
Bay 2:Technical: [T16, T17, T63, T99, T88, T02]
Bay 3:Personal: [P34, P88, P02, P76, P14, P24]

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the fact that LinkedList implements the Queue interface:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class Test {

  public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
    // Create three empty stacks of Bays.
    // Bay 1 linked list
    Queue<String> bayoneStack = new LinkedList<String>();
    // Bay 2 linkd list.
    Queue<String> baytwoStack = new LinkedList<String>();
    // Bay 3 linked list
    Queue<String> baythreeStack = new LinkedList<String>();

    // Open and read text file
    String inputFileName = "PodData4.txt";
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader( inputFileName );

    // Create the FileReader object
    try ( BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( fileReader ); ) {
      // Sort the data into the relevant linked list by type F, T or P.
      String[] strings = br.readLine().split( "," );
      for ( String str : strings ) { 
        switch ( str.charAt( 0 ) ) {
          case 'F':
            bayoneStack.add( str );
            break;
          case 'T':
            baytwoStack.add( str );
            break;
          case 'P':
            baythreeStack.add( str );
            break;
          default:
            // In-case of invalid input
            System.out.println( "" );
        }
      }
    } catch ( IOException ex ) {
      // handle exception;
    } finally {
      fileReader.close();
    }
    // Prints out the linked list stacks showing all Bays.
    System.out.println( "Bay 1:Food: " + bayoneStack.toString() );
    System.out.println( "Bay 2:Technical: " + baytwoStack.toString() );
    System.out.println( "Bay 3:Personal: " + baythreeStack.toString() );

  }
}
```

Comment: Doe's that not mean I'm now disregarding the stack element in the code?

Comment: Its just a sample implementation for your code with Queues. If you need both you probably need to rename beyoneStack in the above to beyoneQueue and duplicate the add. Or you fill up the queue and then invoke on your stack "addAll(queue)".

Comment: Could you give me an example of the invoke on my stack part? Not that advanced with Java yet and sorry for the late reply. I've edited the original code to show the new updates.